# wordpress not rendering site

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, wordpress, ubuntu-16.04

I upgrade my ubuntu server from 14.04 to 16.04. A few of the packages like:

- php
- nginx
- mysql

were updated, I have a small site running on there which was working fine. I was first receiving a 502, which has been corrected as php5 was removed and php-fpm is now php7.0-fpm.

However all I see now is a blank page. I have looked at the nginx error logs but there is nothing to indicate an error. Nor is there an error in the php7.0-fpm log.

I added a test.php to echo a simple value out but that also shows a blank page. It looks like php is not being invoked.

I have updated the /etc/php/7.0/fpm/poo.d/www.conf to listen on: localhost:9000
The nginx config for my site has not changed.

Any thoughts on where it maybe going awry?

Edit 1:

Enabled access logs via /etc/php7/fpm/pool.d/www.conf and can see requests are being sent to fpm:

```
127.0.0.1 -  15/Jan/2017:14:38:53 +0000 "- " 200
127.0.0.1 -  15/Jan/2017:14:39:13 +0000 "- " 200
127.0.0.1 -  15/Jan/2017:14:39:27 +0000 "- " 200
```

Edit 2:

Running:

```
php index.php
```

Does render the site from the terminal. So it is not a php incompatibility issue

Comment: A blank page is usually a php error. Look at your error log, turn on or increase error reporting if nessecary.

Comment: Most probably your php scripts use functions that have been deprecated for years and have been removed in php7.

Comment: @gerald-scheider According to wordpress's site, wordpress is compatible with php7

Comment: Error logs are clear, I have turned up the error logging as well. I think I saw a config setting where you could dump the error in the browser. Might be easier to diagnose that way

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Not sure what version of nginx was previously installed, but I had the following in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/wordpress server:

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
       fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
       fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
       fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
       fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

And changed to:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

Wordpress now rendering